# How to remote desktop (RDP) to hosted agents of Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Azure Pipelines (previously known as VSTS CI/CD pipelines) definition using [Hosted Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted). There are cases when the build works locally but fails on hosted agent due to environment configuration differences. It will greatly improve troubleshooting experience if I can remote desktop to the Hosted Agent assigned to my job, like [what AppVeyor does](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/). Is it possible for Azure Pipelines as well?

Comment: Do you clear it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can’t remote desktop to hosted agent, also the hosted agent may different for different builds/release.

You can refer to this article to check hosted agent software: [Hosted agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted)

You also can setup a private build agent for the build: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that at this moment, you can RDP into the Hosted Agent.

The best you can do is to use powershell to dump all the configuration that is needed and the debug with that info on hand.

Comment: if you want to RDP you need to build custom agent. I don't think Microsoft will ever give this right. it is a PAAS or even SAAS

Comment: I don't think it is technically impossible. AppVeyor already has it supported.

Comment: Its not technically impossible. I was on the dev team a year ago for the hosted agent and this functionality was on our backlog at that time.

We were earlier planning to give you hosted agent access for the time you are running your build/release and also allow you to pause your build/release so that you can debug. At this moment, I don't what is the current status.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, it is not possible to RDP or SSH to an agent hosted by them, from **Capabilities and limitations** section of the documentation:

> Microsoft-hosted agents do not offer:
>
> - The ability to remotely connect.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml