# How do I SSH/RDP into the ADO agents in order to investigate build issues?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am unable to find any documentation on wiki which details approach for SSH/RDP into the ADO agents. Will be good to know the approach for both BTL/ATL agents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remote desktop (RDP) to hosted agents of Azure Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938842/how-to-remote-desktop-rdp-to-hosted-agents-of-azure-pipelines)

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft hosted agents? You don't. You can't. They are assigned when the pipeline is queued and immediately deprovisioned after the pipeline finishes running.

Your own on-premise/self-hosted agents? The same way you'd SSH/RDP into any other machine. If you're having trouble with that, that's something for you to discuss with your networking / infrastructure team.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Microsoft hosted then you can not per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations).  The agent is created on a one-time instance and then torn down as soon as the build is completed.

> Microsoft-hosted agents do not offer:
>
> - **The ability to remotely connect.**
> - The ability to drop artifacts to a UNC file share.
> - The ability to join machines directly to your corporate network.
> - The ability to get bigger or more powerful build machines.
> - The ability to pre-load custom software. You can install software during a pipeline run, such as through tool installer tasks or in a
>   script.
> - Potential performance advantages that you might get by using self-hosted agents that might start and run builds faster.
> - The ability to run XAML builds.

If you are using a self-hosted machine running the agent, then you'd just SSH/RDP into the server like any other and check the [work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#agent-setup) folder.